# Sound on Dell Venue 11 Pro 7140

Tags: sound, 14.10

I really like Ubuntu on this tablet, the only thing stopping me using it full time is the lack of sound, I have Ubuntu 14.10 with the 3.19 kernel installed, blazingly fast but annoyingly silent! I tried opensuse first but the video quality was not so good and still no sound. I can wait for full touch and rotation functionality, happy to ditch windows if the sound can be fixed, anyone have a fix?

Comment: Seems to be a bug, as reported in the following... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1464757 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1477859

Answer (score 0):

The inbuilt speaker works on 4.2rc5 kernel on ubuntu 15.04. I had to pass the following kernel flags while booting intremap=no_x2apic_optout and then use alsamixer to turn on SP0.